# Disabling automatic dissimilarity coding in texshade

Tags: packages, align, environments

The package `texshade` provides an environment to typeset nucleotide and aminoacid alignments. This otherwise great package has a default setting, which I would like to turn off:

By default, `texshade` seems to perform an automatic dissimilarity coding (for lack of a better word), which compares all lines to the first line and codes regions of dissimilarity as follows: identical nucleotides are replaced by dots, dissimilar nucleotides are converted from upper case to lower case letters.

Tex code:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[tightpage]{preview}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{texshade}
\begin{document}
\begin{preview}
    \begin{texshade}{test1.fas}
        \setends{1}{1..12}
        \tintblock{1}{1..3}
        \tintdefault{normal}
        \feature{ttop}{1}{4..12}{translate[Red]}{}
        \ttopspace{5pt}
        \showruler{1}{top}
        \shadingmode{diverse}
        \allmatchresidues{Black}{White}{upper}{up}
        \bottomspace{10pt}
        \feature{bottom}{1}{1..3}{--|[0.75pt]}{R1}
        \feature{bottom}{1}{4..12}{--|[0.75pt]}{R2}
        \hideconsensus
    \end{texshade}
\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

Alignment file `test1.fas`:

```
>Taxon_1
TAAATGGATATA
>Taxon_2
TAAATG----TA
>Taxon_3
TAAATG---CGC
```

When the above TEX code is run on file `test1.fas`, the default dissimilarity coding converts the last two nucleotides of *Taxon_2* to dots and the last three nucleotides in *Taxon_3* from upper case to lower case letters.

[image]

Dissimilarity coding is a common procedure in visualizations of nucleotide and aminoacid alignments, but I would like to turn it off for my current project. How would you suggest to achieve that?

Comment: When you use `\shadingmode{diverse}` you call some default definitions: `\nomatchresidues{Black}{White}{lower}{up}`, `\similarresidues{Black}{White}{lower}{up}`, `\conservedresidues{Black}{White}{{.}}{up}`, `\allmatchresidues{Black}{White}{{.}}{up}` and `\gapchar{-}`. Package documentation does not mention about an option that can be disabled to change the behavior of all shading modes  into this matter. You can redefine those definitions after `\shadingmode{diverse}` is called, why don't do that?

Answer (score 1):

Following the comment of user *OSjerick*, I can indeed disable the dissimilarity coding of `texshade` with the following command options:

```
\shadingmode{diverse}
\allmatchresidues{Black}{White}{upper}{up}
\conservedresidues{Black}{White}{upper}{up}
\nomatchresidues{Black}{White}{upper}{up}
```

The resulting figure then displays nucleotides as upper case letters only.

[image]